# Arreglo de string c++

Tags: c++

Debo realizar un programa teniendo en cuenta que un string se comporta como un arreglo realizar.

1. Perdir una cadena de texto al usuario y:

   - indicar cuantas palabras tiene
   - Indicar cuantas veces aparece cada vocal en la cadena ingresada, si no hay alguna se debe indicar que es 0.

La parte de cuantas palabras tiene, me funciona correctamente. El problema esta en el segundo punto, a la hora de contabilizar la cantidad de vocales, aparecen numeros mayores al que son ingresados.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int ContarPalabras ( char [] );

int main (){

    char cadena [400];
    int vocal_a=0,vocal_e=0,vocal_i=0,vocal_o=0,vocal_u=0;

    cout<<"Ingrese una frase: "<<endl;
    cin.getline(cadena, 400);
    cout<<"La cadena de texto ingresada contiene " <<ContarPalabras(cadena)<<" palabras."<<endl;
    

    // segundo punto

    for (int i=0; i<400; i++){
        switch(cadena[i]){
            case 'a': vocal_a++;break;
            case 'e': vocal_e++;break;
            case 'i': vocal_i++;break;
            case 'o': vocal_o++;break;
            case 'u': vocal_u++;break;
        }
    }

    cout<<"Vocal a: "<<vocal_a<<endl;
    cout<<"Vocal e: "<<vocal_e<<endl;
    cout<<"Vocal i: "<<vocal_i<<endl;
    cout<<"Vocal o: "<<vocal_o<<endl;
    cout<<"Vocal u: "<<vocal_u<<endl;

    return 0;

}

int ContarPalabras (char cad [])
{
    int palabras = 0;
    for (int i=1; cad[i]!='\0'; i++){
        if (cad [i-1]== ' '&&isalpha(cad[i]))
        palabras++;
    }
    if (isalpha(cad[0])) palabras++;
    return palabras;
}
```

Graficamente así se ve el problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estás recorriendo las 400 posiciones del array a lo bestia

```
for (int i=0; i<400; i++){
    switch(cadena[i]){
        case 'a': vocal_a++;break;
        case 'e': vocal_e++;break;
        case 'i': vocal_i++;break;
        case 'o': vocal_o++;break;
        case 'u': vocal_u++;break;
    }
}
```

Aquí solo deberías recorrer la longitud de la cadena introducida por el usuario, ya que el resto del array contendrá valores basura

```
for (int i=0; cadena[i]!='\0'; i++){
    switch(cadena[i]){
        case 'a': vocal_a++;break;
        case 'e': vocal_e++;break;
        case 'i': vocal_i++;break;
        case 'o': vocal_o++;break;
        case 'u': vocal_u++;break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Además está en C++, podría usar `string`.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! :)